# Which HTTP headers to use for subdomain <iframe> embedding?

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, https, embed, iframe

I have a Wordpress site hosted on LightSail (which uses bitnami). The domain is `https://example.com`
On a subdomain `https://sub.example.com` I have another server running. On this server, I want to embed a page from the main domain `https://example.com/a-page`. Currently, I am getting errors that permission is denied.

I have updated the htaccess file like so:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://*.example.com"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' https: *.example.com"
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
```

But the headers don't seem to updating or allowing any iframe embeds. I'm not very well-versed on HTTP Headers so apologies if this is a rather silly question.

Thanks!

Comment: We can't do much without knowing the actual site you are trying this on, maybe looking at the header responses using Chrome DevTools may give you a clue.

Comment: It says that x-frame option is still sameorigin even though I have updated the htaccess file

Comment: Try restarting Apache server, clearing caches etc. Also WordPress has its own interface for HTTP headers, so check this out - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/

If setting it through HTACCESS doesn't seem to work simply use `meta` tags to do the job.

Comment: "use `meta` tags to do the job" - You can't use HTML `meta` tags to embed `X-Frame-Options` or `frame-ancestors` directives of the `Content-Security-Policy` (as stated here) since the browser will ignore them. @DeepakKamat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out that because Lightsail uses a Bitnami deployment of Wordpress, Bitnami overrides the `.htaccess` file.

Instead you have to update the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file by adding the following content:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4.7 >
        Header always setifempty X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://*.example.com
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.4.7 >
        Header always merge X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://*example.com
    </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
```

Reference:
https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/livehelperchat/configuration/enable-framing/

Comment: Although the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) states that the `ALLOW-FROM` directive "is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it." and suggests to use a `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header instead with a `frame-ancestors` directive (your 2nd example).

Comment: Which is precisely why I have raised it on their forums - https://community.bitnami.com/t/allow-from-is-obsolete-how-do-i-use-frame-ancestors/89133

Answer (score -1):

In your case, I think you should use this code in htaccess file to allow Iframe can load with the same origin:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

For more information you can view on this URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Hope can help you finsihed this problem.

Comment: That doesn't work as sameorigin also requires you to have the same server. As I mentioned the subdomain is on a different server.

Comment: may be you site is cache. You clear all cache browser, cache server and test again.